# Please help me to convert C++ algorithm code to Python

Tags: python, c++, algorithm

Can someone help me to fix the re-writing code from C++ to Python:
Initial code is smth like this:

```
    vector<int> b = a;
    unordered_map<int,int> m;
 
    sort(a.begin(),a.end());
    for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++){
        m[a[i]] = i + 1;
    }
 
    vector<int> ans;
    for(int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++){
        ans.push_back(m[b[i]]);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

For Example:

```
Input: [100, 5, 70, 2]
Output: [4, 2, 3, 1]
```

my Python version is here but the answer is not correct:

```
def compress(arr):
    b = []
    b = arr
    m = {}
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        m[arr[i]] = i + 1
    ans = []
    for i in range(len(b)):
        ans.append(m[b[i]])
    return ans
```

My output:

```
Input: [100, 5, 70, 2]
Output: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Please help me where I made a mistake?

Comment: My recommendation is to not try to "translate" code at all, but instead start from a language-agnostic description of the algorithm try to implement it from scratch in the language of your choice.

Comment: I can't even begin to guess *what the code is supposed to do*. Please start by clearly explaining that.

Comment: this code is just giving the latest index of unique element in the list

Comment: Sure, the idea is to compress the given array of uniques element and returning indexes of the elements by keeping the orders of the element as it's shown on the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to sort the input array, also when u sorrting array a and you have assigned the array a to b, then b  automatically sorted and same as a, ssoo u need to create a deep copy of a or assign new list to b of a by appending all element

```
def func(a):
        b =list(a)
        m ={}        
        a.sort()            
        for i in range(len(a)):
            m[a[i]] = i+1  
        ans = []
        for i in range(len(b)):
            ans.append(m[b[i]])
        return ans
```

Comment: yes, but it doesn't affect on my output

Comment: @jam updated solution

Comment: ooooh thanks, I forgot about it! I forgot about deep copy!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Python solution for your problem:

```
>>> a  = [100, 5, 70, 2]
>>> b = range(len(a))
>>> sorted(b, key = lambda x : a[x] )
[3, 1, 2, 0]
>>>
```

If you want your indices start from `1` (not a very pythonic approach):

```
>>> a  = [100, 5, 70, 2]
>>> b = range(1,len(a)+1)
>>> sorted(b, key = lambda x : a[x-1] )
[4, 2, 3, 1]
>>>
```

Comment: Yeap, it's what I'm looking for! Can I ask one more question what if I would have not unique elements and needed these kinds of input/output? `Input: [100, 2, 70, 2]
# Output: [3, 1, 2, 1]`

Comment: regarding your question with duplicate items, the answer you get cannot have duplicate indices, so if your input is `[ 10, 10, 10, 10 ]`, you still get `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, not `[1,1,1,1]`

Comment: yes, that's a point I should return [1,1,1,1] if the elems are similar so their indixes also should be similar

Comment: the question is how I can do it in a more Pythonic way?

Comment: your original code does not return `[3, 1, 2, 1]` for input: `[100, 2, 70, 2]` -- please check that out

Comment: yes, but It's one of the examples of input to check this code

Comment: @Jam if you have the input `[10,10,10,10]`, after `m[a[i]] = i + 1;` the contents of `m` would be: `m[10] = 4`, I don't see how you get `[1,1,1,1]` answer, if `m` contains only a single element `4`

Comment: Sorry, I confused you, and yes, I can't get [1,1,1,1] according to my code, I'll get [4,4,4,4] and I already fixed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You missed this line in the C++ code:

```
sort(a.begin(),a.end());
```

You should sort your `arr` before the first loop.

Comment: yes, but it doesn't affect on my output